# Quiero convertir el segundo decimal de un precio a un redondeo

Tags: javascript

Si por ejemplo un precio es 21.03 se redondee a 21.00,si es 21.04 o 21.06 a 21.05 y si es superior a 21.07 o igual se quede en 21.10. He intentado un round,tambien convirtiendo el decimal a entero para hacer los if, pero nada me sale.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna regla de negocio que defina este comportamiento? Es muy extraño lo que estás planteando aquí. Por lo general los precios no se redondean. Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar tu problema y comparte el código de lo que estás intentando.

Comment: Un redondeo un tanto extraño

Comment: Al añadir un descuento, mi precio se cambia y necesito redondearlo, no tengo un codigo especifico ya que estaba estancado, perdon. Lo que intente fue una funcion que los pase a entero, coja el ultimo numero y haga los if, pero no se como redondearlo luego.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo lo que necesitas es esto

```
<?php
$numero = 15.07;
// divido el numero por el . y obtengo una lista con la parte entera "15" y la decimal "07"
list($entera, $decimal) = explode('.', $numero);
// comparo
if($decimal > 0.7){
    // obtengo el numero redondeado
    echo $entera + 0.10;
} else if( // otras comparaciones ){
    // otras acciones
}

?>
```

Salida: 15.10